# Как вывести в TextView произвольный строковый ресурс?

Tags: android

Моя программа состоит из кнопки и textview. Также имеется 7 строковых ресурсов (p1, p2, ... p7). Я создал обработчик, чтобы по нажатию кнопки в textview выводился ресурс p1, но как сделать так, чтобы вывелся произвольный строковый ресурс из этих 7-ми?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно, что нужен рандом. Предположим, что строковые ресурсы в массиве. Вот код.

```
TextView textView - ваш TextView 
int[] stringResourses = new int[]{p1, p2, ..., p7};
Random r = new Random();
textView.setText(stringResourses[r.nextInt(stringResourses.length+1)]);
```

Этот код нужно поместить в обработчик нажатия, и все должно работать.

Comment: Лучше, конечно, в метод, генерирущий рандом, число засунуть `stringResourses.lengh()+1`, чтобы не хардкодить.

Comment: @argamidon, @nekaneka, работает, только вот из-за stringResourses.length+1 выдает ошибку - выход за пределы массива, если убрать + 1, то все норм. Плюс тип массива - String, я ведь использую строки, как элементы массива, студия  еще зачем-то попросила объявить stringResourses как final. На этом вроде как все, но все же интересно, можно ли как-нибудь доставать эти произвольные строки, скажем, из отдельного файла или, например, из R.strings.* ? А то как-то неэстетично будет смотреться в коде объявление массива с сотней строковых элементов. ))

Comment: Можно описать в R.strings массив из string, и тогда не нужно будет менять в коде ничего. Достаточно будет взять массив из R.strings.

Comment: @nekaneka, то есть описать массив в strings.xml?

Comment: Да. Выглядит очень просто.
        <string-array name="array_name">
        <item>элемент 1</item>
        <item>элемент 2</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: @nekaneka,огромное спасибо!)