# Анимация появления текста в TextView

Tags: android-textview, анимация, android

Мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку появлялся текст как бы размытый и потом примерно за две секунды становился чётким. Как это можно сделать?

Или же чтобы при нажатии на кнопку текст постепенно появлялся, то есть при нажатии чтобы он из полностью прозрачного постепенно становился полностью насыщенным. Как это можно сделать?

Сам текст, который должен появляться при нажатии на кнопку, берётся из массива строк.

Если вы знаете как что-то из этого реализовать, то напишите, пожалуйста, спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Нашёл способ, чтобы текст постепенно из прозрачного становился видимым.

В папке **res/anim** создаем файл анимации, например tv_animation.xml

Содержание .xml файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromAlpha="0.0"
 android:toAlpha="1.0"
 android:duration="1000">
</alpha>
```

В активити задаём переменные

```
TextView tv;
Animation anim;
```

В методе, который отвечает за вывод текста в TextView, пишем:

```
anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.tv_animation);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerText);
        tv.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 5):

Есть вот такая либа. Мне лично очень нравится. Мечтаю наконец где-нибудь ее использовать...

[Тык](https://github.com/matthewrkula/SecretTextView)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Это просто. [Вот](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/alpha.php) анимация появления. Разобраться очень просто. Если массив строк в strings описан, то вам поможет вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/400342/android-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-textview-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81#400652) вопрос.